# Equivalence relation for "almost equal to"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of the set of natural numbers.  We say that $A$ is almost equal to $B$, and write $A \approx B$, if there exists a finite subset $X \subset$ (natural numbers) such that $A \cup X = B \cup X$. Let $S$ be the set of equivalence classes for the relation "is almost equal to" on power set of natural numbers.
Then show that

> $\# S =$ cardinality of the power set of natural numbers.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the exercise? What have you attempted to do to solve the problem? What are you struggling to understand?

Comment: Have you at least worked out some equivalence classes? There are some that seem more or less easy to recognize.

Comment: Let $M_X$ denote the equivalence class for all sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A \cup X= B \cup X$. We can see that the equality holds for $X= A \cup B$. Hence the set $A \cup B$ describes an equivalence class for all subsets $A$ and $B$. Therefore, the number of such equivalence classes is equal to the number of sets which can be formed by the union of all possible $A$s and $B$s.

Comment: Since $A$ and $B$ are both subsets of $\NN$, $A \cup B$ is also a subset of $\NN$, therefore the number of equivalence classes is equal to the total number of subsets of $\NN$. Hence, $$\#S=\#P(\NN).$$ I know this is wrong but I can't understand how to do it correctly

Comment: Why have 3 people voted to close this question? It seems perfectly fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

This is an anwser that aim to gives more insight on what are these equivalence class, and show that there's an interesting underlying structure.

First, let's define the symmetric difference : $A\Delta B = (A\cup B) \backslash (A\cap B)$

Now, $A\sim B$ if and only if $A\Delta B$ is finite. This imply that there exists a finite set $X$ such that $B= A \Delta X$, and that for every finite set $X$, $A\sim (A\Delta X)$

Then, the equivalence class of a set $A$ is exactly

$$\tilde A = \left\{ B = A\Delta X | X \text{ finite} \right\}$$

In addition to that, the map 
$$\begin{array} 
.\phi_A: & P_f(\Bbb N) & \to & \tilde{A} \\
& X & \mapsto & A\Delta X
\end{array}$$ 
is bijective

As there is a countable number of finite sets, each class is countable, so this imply that there is an uncountable number of classes.

And if we remark that $(P_f(\Bbb N), \Delta)$ is an abelian group, and that

$$\begin{array} 
.\psi: & P_f(\Bbb N) \times P(\Bbb N) & \to & P(\Bbb N) \\
& (X,A) & \mapsto & X\Delta A
\end{array}$$

is a group action where $(P_f(\Bbb N), \Delta)$ act on $P(\Bbb N)$ by symmetric difference. The equivalence class of $A$ is then the orbit of $A$

Comment: "Now, A∼B if and only if AΔB is finite. This imply that there exists a finite set X such that B=AΔX, and that for every finite set X", I didn't quite understand this part completely

Comment: @112358 : First, remark that $A\cup (A\Delta B) = B \cup (A\Delta B)$, that gives you the $\Leftarrow$ . Now for the other direction : Take a set $X$ such that $A\cup X = B\cup X$, and consider $\tilde{X} = X \cap (A\Delta B)$. Now $\tilde{X} \cup A = (X\cup A) \cap (A \cup (A\Delta B)) = (X\cup B) \cap (A\cup B) =  (X\cup A) \cap (A \cup (A\Delta B)) = \tilde{X} \cup B$, and $\tilde{X}$ is finite. *next comment for the end*

Comment: We just have to show that $\tilde{X} = A\Delta B$. Suppose $x\in \tilde{X}$, then $x\in X\cap (A\Delta B)$ hence $x\in A\Delta B$. If $x\in A\Delta B$, then $x\in A$ but not in $B$ (or the opposite), that means that $x\in X$ (or else, $A\cup X \neq B\cup X$), hence $x\in X\cap (A\Delta B) = \tilde{X}$ : the equivalence is then proved

Comment: Thank You so much! Could you explain the mapping a bit more?

Comment: @Tryss: You've shown that there are uncountably many equivalence classes, but it takes some more work to show that they are in bijection with $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ (and not some uncountable set of a different cardinality).

Comment: @CliveNewstead that's exactly where I'm stuck, could you help me out a bit?

Comment: @CliveNewstead : Not much works with a little cardinal arithmetic (or none if you assume the axiom of continuum) : Let $I$ be a set of indices such that $X_i, i\in I$ are the equivalences class of this relation. Then $\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i \simeq I\times \Bbb N$ (because the $X_i$ are disjoints), but $\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i = P(\Bbb N)$, so $|I| \times \aleph_0 = 2^{\aleph_0}$, and this imply $|I| = 2^{\aleph_0}$

Comment: @Tryss How did you get $B=AΔX$ from $X= AΔB$? Could you also explain the map a bit more?

Comment: @112358 : $A\Delta( A\Delta B) = (A\Delta A) \Delta B = \emptyset \Delta B = B$.

Comment: How do you get the bijection between P(N) and the set of equivalent classes?

Comment: Since X can only be finite what about the infinite sets in P(N). are they not involved in the mapping?

Comment: @112358 : My mapping (dependent on $A$) is a bijection between the finite sets and the elements in a **fixed** equivalence class (the one of $A$) : that way, you describe exactly what are the elements in the class of $A$ (this is why this answer has an interest). This gives you the result that the cardinality of each class is $\aleph_0$ (the cardinality of $\Bbb N$). I don't explicitely give the bijection between P(N) and the set of classes, but I use a cardinality argment (see my comment that answer CliveNewstead). If something is not clear, ask questions about it ;)

Answer (score 2):

To construct such subsets of $\mathbb N$ that they differ from each other infinitely many, you can use the fact that we have infinitely many primes.

More details: You have $2^{\aleph_0}$ subset of primes, for each of them correspond subset of $\mathbb N$ that its elements are numbers that they are have at least one divisors in the corresponding subset of primes.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more, what are the sequences you're talking about? I've never come across such sequences

Comment: @112358 I added details.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\{q_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be an enumeration of the rationals in $\mathbb{R}$.

For every real $r$ choose a sequence of all different rationals that converges to it. Let $I(r)$ be the set of $n$ such that $q_n$ is used in this sequence.

Show that $I(r)$ and $I(r')$ can overlap at most in a finite set when $r \neq r'$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more, I have very basic knowledge of set theory and I didn't understand your comment completely.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this is with the Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein theorem, i.e. to find an injection $S \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and an injection $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to S$.

- There is an injection $S \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ defined by sending an equivalence class in $S$ to a (fixed) choice of representative.
- We can define an injection $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to S$ using an encoding trick: we'll encode each subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ as another subset $\widehat{A} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, in such a way that if $A \ne B$ then $\widehat{A}$ and $\widehat{B}$ differ by infinitely many elements (i.e. $\widehat{A} \not\approx \widehat{B}$).

  We define the encoding as follows. Fix a partition $\{ U_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ of $\mathbb{N}$ into countably many countably infinite sets. There are many ways of doing this; pick your favourite... the main point is that the $U_n$ are pairwise disjoint and are all infinite. Given $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, let
  $$\widehat{A} = \bigcup_{n \in A} U_n$$
  You can check that the map $A \mapsto \widehat{A}$ satisfies the desired property.

  Now define $\varphi : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to S$ by letting $\varphi(A) = [\widehat{A}]_{\approx}$. The fact that $A \ne B$ implies $\widehat{A} \not\approx \widehat{B}$ says precisely that $\varphi$ is injective.