# The equivalence relation on the power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $X$ be a set. We can define the equivalence relation on the power set $2^{X}$ in the following way: the sets $A,B\in 2^{X}$ are equivalent if the symmetric difference $A\triangle B$ is finite.

**Questions:** Is there any information about this equivalence relation? Is there a standard notation for this equivalence relation?

Comment: I have seen $=_{/fin}$ and $=_{fin}$ in texts on set theory.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Can you tell me what are the texts?

Comment: Set Theory : An Introduction To Independence Proofs, by Kenneth Kunen....Also $A\subset_{/fin}B$, which means that $A$ \ $B$ is finite..... Others I'm not sure. Likely something by Jech.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks! Very interesting notation.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I can't find this in the book. Can you help me?

Comment: Perhaps my memory is wrong. But in the 1st edition, see Exercises 22,23,23 of Chapter II.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks! That's it.

Answer (score 3):

Let $P_f(X)$ be the set of finite subsets of $X$. As shown in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1770086), $(P_f(X), \Delta)$ is a commutative group which [acts on the right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)) on $P(X)$ by symmetric difference:
\begin{align} 
P(X) \times P_f(X) & \to P(X) \\
(E,F) &\mapsto E \mathrel{\Delta} F
\end{align}
Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation on $P(X)$ defined by $A \sim B$ if and only if $A \mathrel{\Delta} B$ is finite. Then the $\sim$-class of a subset $A$ of $X$ is the [orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)#Orbits_and_stabilizers) of $A$ under this action, since $B = A \mathrel{\Delta} (A \mathrel{\Delta} B)$.

I agree with Daniel Wainfleet that $=_\text{fin}$ is a reasonable notation for $\sim$.

Comment: Thanks! I have seen this answer, but i can't understand why is this group action needed in this case?

Comment: I just answered to your question "is there any information about this equivalence relation"?